# Problema de concatenación en T-SQL de SQL Server

Tags: tsql

Si tengo esta línea de código:

`set @usuario= (SELECT usuario FROM tbl_usuario WHERE id= 1)`

En la variable `@usuario` me guarda el nombre de usuario seleccionado, pero ya que quiero hacer un `stored procedure` quiero concantenar unas variables como:

`set @usuario= (SELECT @campo FROM @tabla WHERE id= @id_usuario)`

Pero SQL Server no me lo permite, me marca error, por favor, no sugerirme que haga esto:

`set @usuario= 'SELECT ' + @campo  + ' FROM ' + @tabla + ' WHERE id= ' @id_usuario`

Ya que yo necesito que la consulta me devuelva el dato para imprimirlo como un mensaje con `print`, no necesito que me devuelva un datatable. ¿Me explico?

Comment: cómo te aseguras que el nombre en `@tabla` tenga una columna llamada `usuario`?

Comment: Ignoremos eso, solo fue una supocision, o si quieres, haz de cuenta que esta es la linea

Comment: `set @usuario= 'SELECT ' +  @campo +  ' FROM ' + @tabla + ' WHERE id= ' @id_usuario`

Comment: @AnthonyMedina podrías indicarme que versión de `sql-server`estás usando. Debido que a partir del **`SQL Server 2012`** tienes la función [`CONCAT`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/hh231515.aspx) que sirve para concatenar cadenas y poder ayudarte con tu problema.

Comment: Procura incluir el error completo que te muestra.

Answer (score 0):

Intenta con esto, ya realicé algunas pruebas y me funcionó:

```
DECLARE @sqlCommand NVARCHAR(1000)
DECLARE @IdUsuario VARCHAR(75)
DECLARE @Campo VARCHAR(64)
SET @IdUsuario = '123'
SET @sqlCommand = 'SELECT @Campo = NombreUsuario FROM ' + @Tabla + ' WHERE IdUsuario = ' + @IdUsuario
EXECUTE sp_executesql @sqlCommand, N'@IdUsuario NVARCHAR(75), @campo VARCHAR(64) OUTPUT', @IdUsuario = @IdUsuario, @Campo = @Campo OUTPUT

DECLARE @miVariableResultado VARCHAR(64)

SELECT  @miVariableResultado = @campo

PRINT @miVariableResultado
```

Comment: No es lo que necesito, ya que en realidad, yo no quiero que me retorne un datatable sino, un mensaje con el campo, de esa manera que dices, me retorna un datatable

Comment: Con un print a @usuario haciendolo de esta manera, solo me retorna la consulta SQL como un string, ya interpretado obviamente con los datos enviados mediante los parametros

Comment: He comprendido, disculpa, ahora mismo trabajo en la corrección de mi respuesta

Comment: @AnthonyMedina listo, he actualizado mi respuesta

Answer (score 0):

espero y esto sea lo que buscas:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[spPacienteEnCola]
@tabla varchar(50) = '',
@funcion int = 0,
@campo varchar(50),
@id_usuario varchar(10)
AS
begin
    create table #temp (nombre varchar(30))
    declare @VConsulta varchar(max) = ''
    declare @msg varchar(max) = ''
    declare @nombre VARCHAR(MAX)
    declare @sql varchar(100)
    declare @usuario VARCHAR(MAX)
    select @sql = 'insert into #temp select top 1 '+@campo+' from '+@tabla+' where id='+@id_usuario
    exec (@sql)
if @funcion = 0
    begin
        set @msg = N'No has enviado el valor de @funcion'
        print @msg
    end

if @funcion = 1
    begin
        set @nombre = (select nombre from #temp)
        select @nombre
        drop table #temp
    end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

La aproximación que hice en algún momento fue:

```
EXEC ('INSERT INTO [dbo].[MiTabla](X, Y, Mes, Año, ' + @TipoString + ', ' + @FechaString + ', ' + @RegString + ') VALUES('''
      + @OB + ''', ''' + @Clave + ''', ''' + @Mes + ''', ''' + @Año + ''', ''' + @Monto + ''', GETDATE(), ''' + @Usuario + ''')')
```

Esto fue así porque los registros los actualizo en el mismo SP, así que tener los datos ya guardados y solo hacer `UPDATE` sobre la tabla me funcionaba.

Si solo será un dato, o no necesitas hacer grandes operaciones, puedes declarar una `#tablaTemporal` y guardar ahí tu consulta:

```
CREATE TABLE #Nombre (Valor NVARCHAR(50))
EXEC('INSERT INTO #Nombre SELECT ...' + @ColumnaVariable + ' FROM ...')
```